# Sql - Modelar Banco de Dados

Tags: sql

Agradeceria ajuda. Nâo sei como fazer para criar tabelas no banco de dados SQL

Meu problema é esse:

tenho um usuário com um pedido com vários ítens.

Ja tenho a tabela usuarios e produtos

Como faço para criar esta tabela que contenha um pedido e vários produtos relacionados a ele?

Obrigado

Comment: Se eu entendi bem, e um relacionamento 1 para n, então você deve criar a tabela pedido e nela colocar uma chave estrangeira para a chave primaria de produtos, se não for isso ou você queira o código em sql avise

Comment: Pesquise no Google < diagrama der sistema de pedidos > terá algumas ideias.

Comment: @SergioGuerik: Qual é o gerenciador de banco de dados: SQL Server? Oracle database? MariaDB?

Comment: Arcashaid, se você puder me mostrar através de úm codigo como fazer isso seria ótimo. obrigado

Comment: Jose diz, o Banco é SQL

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Considerando que suas tabelas já criadas contenham a seguinte estrutura:

**Tabela Usuarios**

```
PK idUsuarios int
Nome varchar(30)
NomeCompleto varchar(255)
```

**Tabela Produtos**

```
PK idProdutos int
Descricao varchar(255)
ValorUnit decimal(10,4)
```

### As novas tabelas desejadas

**Tabela Pedidos**

```
PK idPedidos int
FK idUsuarios int
DataPedido datetime
ValorTotal decimal(10,4)
```

**Código SQL**

```
create table Pedidos
(idPedidos int identity,
 idUsuarios int,
 DataPedido datetime,
 ValorTotalPedido decimal(10,4))
```

**Tabela PedidosProduto** -> Vínculo dos vários produtos do pedido

```
PK idPedidos int
PK idProdutos int
Qtde decimal(7,4) -> Decimal para produtos fracionados por exemplo
```

**Código SQL**

```
create table PedidosProdutos
(idPedidos int,
 idProdutos int,
 Qtde decimal(7,4))
```

Observe que será possível cadastrar vários produtos utilizando o ID do mesmo pedido. Ex:

```
+---------------------------+
| PEDIDO | PRODUTO |  QTDE  |
+---------------------------+
| 1      | 1029    | 1.0000 | 
| 2      | 1023    | 3.0000 |
| 3      | 1993    | 8.3100 |  
+---------------------------+
```

Comment: Me parece que na tabela Pedidos é necessário acrescentar o id do usuário como chave estrangeira, de modo que seja possível identificar de quem é o pedido. // Na tabela PedidosProduto eu acrescentaria a unidade do item e também o valor unitário do item. // Quando se faz um pedido, normalmente se registra o preço unitário do produto no momento do pedido.

Comment: @JoséDiz Todas estas ressalvas são válidas sim, obrigado, no entanto, foi uma ilustração simples da criação da tabela com os vários produtos. Se fossemos fazer um levantamento por completo de todos os requisitos, poderá ter ainda muitos outros campos.

Comment: Muito obrigado Ismael pelo exemplo. Vou tentar modelar desta forma. José Diz, obrigado pelo complemento.